# Three.js OrbitControls enableRotate/Pan = false don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to set `.enableRotate` and `.enablePan` to **false** on my perspectiveCamera with OrbiteControls

I already tried to set them, as it was not working I find a work around using:

```
controls.maxPolarAngle = 0;
controls.maxAzimuthAngle = - Math.PI;
```

But as there is not something like that for `.enablePan` I am stuck there. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I used it ?

Here is the code pen if you prefer work on it or try it : https://codepen.io/greg_o/pen/jdwZYZ

I guess this is the part of the code that interest you :

```
function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 68;
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    controls.maxDistance = 300;
    controls.minDistance = 30;
    controls.enableRotate = false;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = 0;
    controls.maxAzimuthAngle = - Math.PI;
    controls.enablePan = false;
 }
```

*Just wanna say that the pen is originally from Nikita Skargovskii*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest version of `three.js` and `OrbitControls` seems to solve the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exRQYo

You have used release 84 before which is more than two years old. Always use the latest revision of `three.js` and also ensure that files from the example directory (like `OrbitControls`) match the version of your `three.js` file.